# Access to one data collection from multiple logged users

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am solving following problem and I will grateful for some advice because I can move my project ahead, so I hope this question don't break any rules.

In my app I have 2 rest controller:

1. for data storing
2. for data fetching

It should works something like that: Some user send data to database with first rest controller. Each data object has also recipient property, so I need put this recipient into collection. That collection will be available for each user. When data are stored, user get response 200.

When another use controller for data fetching hi check this collection, if  contains his id. If yes, he load it from database and return to user response with these data. Else he is waiting and in loop is checking this collection until it will be contains his id or waiting time expire. If during checking this collection he is found his id, he remove this id and fetch data and return it as response else return empty object.

Can you tell me if spring contains some feature for that? Or if not how it could be did by pure java? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding , you need to preserve some value after each POST/PUT. So that you can use this value before GET.

I would suggest to you some in memory cache. ( Something like guava as it provides many methods for operating on cache)
Or check if you can achieve this with Spring Cache.

If you are using MongoDB, you can use cacheable collection.

Comment: Hi thanks for your effort at first. I thought about it, but I didn't found anything for my requirements. In cache I should store only data for get method, or not? Also it is possible filter this cache, for example by id? I do not have a lot experience with cache, so could you show me small example how should it work in my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Well now I am on my mobile device, and its 2:00 in India, for now I would suggest you to explore caching thing, or else will cacth you aftee 7-8 hours of sleep 

Comment: ok thanks :) I have idea how should it works, but I don't know if it possible do it with cache. For example when rest controller for storing data in db send data, it should be stored in db and also in cache right? And if another user tried fetch data addressed to him, he check db, and if no data here to him, he will be checking this data in cache for specific time. Is possible to do that in cache and work with cache like with some list?

Comment: In fetch call, first cache is checked if not in cache then go to db. Cache is nothing but just  main memory (we can even use hashmap etc) primary motive of cache is optimization

Comment: I also understand cache as something for optimization, for data which are fetched a lot of times. But my data will sent by client, and stored until another client which is receiver fetch these data. It is also usage of cache? It is little advanced topic I think, so I couldn't find any resources as example to solve my problem.